# Почему может не работать выборка?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть примерная структура бд:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT
    players.id AS player_id,
    teams_players.team_id AS team_id,
    users.name AS user_name,
    players.game_id AS game_id
FROM
    `users`
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams_players` ON `players`.`id` = `teams_players`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams` ON `teams_players`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`
WHERE
    (
        `users`.`id` IN(
        SELECT
            IF(
                `sender_id` = 42,
                `receiver_id`,
                `sender_id`
            )
        FROM
            `friends`
        WHERE
            `status` = 1
        )
    ) AND(`players`.`game_id` = '3')
```

Выбираю друзей определенного пользователя со статусом 1, у которых игрок из игры 3.
Получаю такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь хочу вывести игроков у которых команда не равна 2(или её вообще нет)

```
SELECT
    players.id AS player_id,
    teams_players.team_id AS team_id,
    users.name AS user_name,
    players.game_id AS game_id
FROM
    `users`
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams_players` ON `players`.`id` = `teams_players`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams` ON `teams_players`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`
WHERE
    (
        `users`.`id` IN(
        SELECT
            IF(
                `sender_id` = 42,
                `receiver_id`,
                `sender_id`
            )
        FROM
            `friends`
        WHERE
            `status` = 1
    )
    ) AND(`players`.`game_id` = '3') AND(teams.id <> 2)
```

Возвращает ноль строк. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: *Что я делаю не так?* 1) Что у Вас делает в источнике таблица `teams`? Она же не используется... 2) Условие отбора `AND(teams_players.team_id <> 2)` превращает LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN.Поэтому и ноль... запрос не соответствует требуемой логике, короче...

Comment: отредактировал запрос, teams теперь используется, и как тогда правильно сделать join?

Comment: @edvardpotter а что это за редактор схем?

Comment: @norbornen дизайнер phpmyadmin

Comment: так вот `teams.id <> 2` разумеется возвращает 0 строк. Ибо до этого из было две. первая не попадает, потому что `2 <> 2`, а вторая не попадает потому что любое сравнение с null не работает. на null надо проверять всегда явно (`teams.id <> 2 or teams.id is null`)

Comment: @mike, да null и смущал больше всего, по глупости проверял `teams.id <> 2 or teams.id = null`, спасибо за помощь. Добавьте ответ, отмечу правильным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автор ответа [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike). Ошибка была в неявном сравнение id команды с `null`. Исправленный вариант ниже:

```
SELECT
    players.id AS player_id,
    teams_players.team_id AS team_id,
    users.name AS user_name,
    players.game_id AS game_id
FROM
    `users`
LEFT JOIN `players` ON `users`.`id` = `players`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams_players` ON `players`.`id` = `teams_players`.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `teams` ON `teams_players`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`
WHERE
    (
        `users`.`id` IN(
        SELECT
            IF(
                `sender_id` = 42,
                `receiver_id`,
                `sender_id`
            )
        FROM
            `friends`
        WHERE
            `status` = 1
    )
    ) AND(`players`.`game_id` = '3') AND(teams.id <> 2 or teams.id is null)
```